# Chrome: Submit form in new tab with keyboard

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

Google Chrome/Chromium allows you to submit a form in a new tab by middle-clicking the submit button.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or extension that allows this by using the keyboard only?

---

In Opera, you can simply press Shift+Return for that.

Comment: Tried with the search form here on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> resulted in submission in new tab

Comment: This seems to be a speciality here. it does not work e.g. on https://duckduckgo.com/

Comment: I just tried on [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/). `Ctrl`+`Enter` did nothing, but `Shift`+`Enter` submitted in a new window.

Comment: Shift+Enter works on duckduckgo, too - to open a new window, but not a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> submits the form in a new window.

There is currently no functionality submit a form in a new tab.